# Webscrape from API with Rvest or JsonLite

Tags: r, json, rvest

I am trying to scrape data from this [website](https://www.domstol.no/no/nar-gar-rettssaken/Search). I have successfully done it before, but they have changed the site. Is it possible to extract from their API, if they have it at all?

Alternatively, I could do it with RSelenium but it takes a lot of time.

[image: Inpect of the network]

I found this is the dev tool, link as such https://www.domstol.no/api/episerver/v3/beramming/ and it does return the complete dataset that I want. This is shown below:

[image]

How am I able to request this into R?

Comment: If they have a self-documenting API, then yes. Otherwise, you (or somebody) is stucking crawling the website looking for endpoints. In my experience, I find enabling the dev-console in your browser (perhaps `F12` then reload the page) and looking at the network traffic, one can typically find endpoints that suggest APIs, formal or otherwise. Good luck.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for your comment! I tried that, but struggles to find anything concrete. I found this https://www.domstol.no/api/episerver/v3/beramming/ in the network stuff but I don't know how to request from it. Could you guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Unfortunately, I get a 405 for that link. Frankly, exploring an API from an organization that doesn't clearly document it suggests one of two things: (1) they only give the documentation/support to specific people (perhaps those who pay for it?); or (2) they have not yet documented it. If the latter, then request it from them and they can do a much better job than I can. If the former, though, I don't have full guidance other than looking in the browser dev-console and playing with various URLs. No magic, just time and lots of 404s/405s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to mimic that POST request sending blank param values in the JSON body. None of the headers or cookies are required.

```
library(httr2)
library(magrittr)

r <- request("https://www.domstol.no/api/episerver/v3/beramming/") %>% 
  req_body_json(list('To' = '', 'From' = '', 'CaseAbout' = '', 'CaseNumber' = '')) %>% 
  req_perform() %>%
  resp_body_json()


library(purrr)

df <- map_dfr(r, ~ data.frame(.x))
```

---

Or as per OP in comments re df from result of call

```
library(httr2)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

df <- request("https://www.domstol.no/api/episerver/v3/beramming/") %>% 
  req_body_json(list('To' = '', 'From' = '', 'CaseAbout' = '', 'CaseNumber' = '')) %>% 
  req_perform() %>%
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>% 
  tibble()
```